# How to scroll horizontal UICollectionView while clicking on cell like instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

Please solve my query regarding the scroll view.

How can we auto scroll the collection view on another cell like Instagram when we adding filter on image.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift < 2.x you can do something like:**

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

**In Swift 3 you can do something like this**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndex, section: sectionIndex)

collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.right, animated: true)
```

The various Scroll Position provided by swift are:

> centeredHorizontally /
>   centeredVertically/bottom/left/right/top

Comment: thanks, Please convert this in objective-c

Because it not works 

** [CollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];**

Answer (score 0):

```
 [liveVideoCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                        animated:YES];
```